# how to solove 'Login Required' problem when using google sheet script?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

The goal is whenever a new version was created, an auto-trigger function will get this spreadsheet's latest history version date and set it to the target cell.

I use onEdit function to trigger it.

The code is like this:

```
function listRevisions(fileId) {
  var revisions = Drive.Revisions.list(fileId)

  if (revisions.items && revisions.items.length > 0) {

    var latestVersion = revisions.items[revisions.items.length - 1]

    var date = new Date(latestVersion.modifiedDate)

    Logger.log('Date: %s, File size (bytes): %s', date.toLocaleString(), latestVersion.fileSize);
    return date.toLocaleString()
  } 
  else {
    Logger.log('No revisions found.')
    return 
  }
}

function onEdit(e){
  if(e.source.getActiveSheet().getName()==="targetSheetName"){
    var dateString =  listRevisions(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId())
    targetSheet.getRange(1,7,1,1).setValue(dateString )
  }
}
```

I can manually run listRevisions function and its fine with me,the problem is when I excute the listRevisions function by onEdit.It always give me a error text like

> "GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.revisions.list failed with error: Login Required
> at listRevisions"

Since I am not quite familier with google api stuff,could someone kindly help me figure out how to solove this problem?

Comment: If you are using `onEdit` as the simple trigger, I guessed that the reason of your issue is due to that `Drive.Revisions.list` is used as the simple trigger. In this case, please use the installable trigger of OnEdit and test it again. By the way, when you use the installable OnEdit trigger, I would like to recommend to rename the function name from `onEdit` to others. Because the function name of `onEdit` is used for the simple trigger. So when the installable OnEdit trigger is installed to the function of `onEdit`, this function is run 2 times with the asynchronous processing.

Comment: In addition to Tanaike's comment can you please share the appsscript.json content?

Comment: @JoseVasquez what do you mean the 'appsscript.json content' ? where can I export them？

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users how have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

thanks to @Tanaike 's advice.

> If you are using onEdit as the simple trigger, I guessed that the reason of your issue is due to that Drive.Revisions.list is used as the simple trigger. In this case, please use the installable trigger of OnEdit and test it again. By the way, when you use the installable OnEdit trigger, I would like to recommend to rename the function name from onEdit to others. Because the function name of onEdit is used for the simple trigger. So when the installable OnEdit trigger is installed to the function of onEdit, this function is run 2 times with the asynchronous processing.

now I can do it now~
Thank you again @Tanaike